# Where to find the redemtion64.tlh

Tags: c++, outlook-redemption

I'm new to redemption, so maybe this is an already answered question. But i stuck at this point. I've just downloadad the redemptionloader and imported the files into my MFC c++ project. But - the #import does not find redemtion64.tlh. Maybe i'm doing something wrong here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The tlh file is created when you import the type library:

```
#import "libid:2D5E2D34-BED5-4B9F-9793-A31E26E6806E" rename_namespace("Redemption") raw_interfaces_only
```